# How to Use Flutter Using Syncfusion Control Pannel

Tags: android, flutter, syncfusion

I have downloaded syncfusion, I don't know how to run flutter code in that. Please, anyone, know about it.

Answer (score 0):

After installing our Syncfusion control build, open the control panel and click on the Explore Demo Source button as in the following screenshot,

[Control Panel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkvsV.png)

It will navigate you to the demo folder which is named 'Sample Browser'.

In your IDE(Say Vs code/Android studio), kindly navigate to that location, and by default, it prompts you to get packages, click on it or you can manually get the packages by using any one of the following commands in the terminal,

**'flutter packages get' or 'flutter pub get'**

After getting the packages successfully, you can run the samples in your IDE to view our samples.

Thanks,
Dharanitharan. P